# Anyone has a clue why I'm experiencing this crash in NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, upload, nsurlsession

Getting a lot of crash reports with this stack trace... unable to fix it.
Had suspicion that it has something to do with me manipulating cookies in the shared instance of NSHTTPCookieStorage, so i have added code to do it on the same thread, but I'm still expiring this.
Any thoughts or ideas will be much appreciated.

```
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                       0x23363dc4 CFURLCopyAbsoluteURL + 60
1   CFNetwork                            0x22e87039 HTTPCookieStorage::copyCookiesForURL(__CFURL const*, unsigned char) + 74
2   CFNetwork                            0x22f65ed1 -[NSHTTPCookieStorage cookiesForURL:] + 90
3   CFNetwork                            0x22eef4e1 -[__NSURLBackgroundSession requestWithCookiesApplied:] + 218
4   CFNetwork                            0x22ef0505 -[__NSURLBackgroundSession _onqueue_uploadTaskForRequest:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:] + 126
5   CFNetwork                            0x22ef03e5 __80-[__NSURLBackgroundSession uploadTaskForRequest:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 38
6   CFNetwork                            0x22eefadf __68-[__NSURLBackgroundSession performBlockOnQueueAndRethrowExceptions:]_block_invoke + 84
7   libdispatch.dylib                    0x31577c6f _dispatch_client_callout + 20
8   libdispatch.dylib                    0x31581559 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 46
9   CFNetwork                            0x22eefa0f -[__NSURLBackgroundSession performBlockOnQueueAndRethrowExceptions:] + 208
10  CFNetwork                            0x22ef0365 -[__NSURLBackgroundSession uploadTaskForRequest:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:] + 218
11  CFNetwork                            0x22f497b7 -[NSURLSession uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile:] + 32
12  Pogoplug                             0x001a3ca5 __46-[CENetworkManager uploadRequest:finishBlock:]_block_invoke (CENetworkManager.m:377)
13  Foundation                           0x2414abfd __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 6
14  Foundation                           0x240b5ac5 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 146
15  Foundation                           0x240a8505 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 766
16  Foundation                           0x2414d557 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
17  libdispatch.dylib                    0x315824d3 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 1460
18  libdispatch.dylib                    0x31581da1 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 82
19  libdispatch.dylib                    0x31584491 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 386
20  libdispatch.dylib                    0x315858a3 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 104
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x316f8da9 _pthread_wqthread + 666
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x316f8afc start_wqthread + 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the cause after I managed to reproduce this issue while debugging, and its so silly on my part - its happening when url == nil for upload request.

Not sure why Apple allow to create `NSURLMutableRequest` with url == nil though, and not throwing exception in `[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:]` method.

Comment: Can you please share the solution?

I do not have upload task and the NSURL is not nil on my requests but I am facing the same issues. A small percentage of the app users are having similar crash

Comment: @WizMeister can you please share more about that ... I m getting a lot of crashes from the users ...

Comment: nothing more to share - url was nil and request was created but crashed NSURLSession when it tried to execute it.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest check once with Instruments Tool, you will have a clear picture why and where exactly it is crashing.

Comment: Its not happening all the time, its only happening to small percentage of users, very infrequently

Comment: Anyway you have to reproduce it somehow and need to check.